# Why is there such a large price difference between the A350 and B787?

Tags: cost, boeing-787, aircraft-manufacturer, airbus-a350

What are the reasons for quite significant difference in price between the Airbus A350 and Boeing 787? List prices for the A350-900 and 787-9 are around 317 million USD and 190 million USD respectively.

Comment: Those prices are not the actual prices airlines pay for those planes. They get big discounts and more complex contractual terms. It's not like buying a box of pasta

Comment: @Afe you should put that as an answer.

Comment: @ Afe - you're paying way too much for pasta.  Who's your pasta guy?

Comment: I am aware of that however the typical discounts are pretty much the same for both: https://www.forbes.com/sites/afontevecchia/2013/05/21/boeing-bleeding-cash-as-787-dreamliners-cost-200m-but-sell-for-116m-but-productivity-is-improving/, https://simpleflying.com/airbus-reveals-on-average-airlines-get-50-off-airline-list-prices/

Answer (score 2):

Those prices are not the actual prices airlines pay for those planes. They get big discounts and more complex contractual terms. It's not like buying a box of pasta.
In conclusion, you can't assume that the price difference means a different cost of the components for the manufacturer